# how to recode my jquery/javascript function to be more generic and not require unique identifiers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, generics, dry

I've created a function that works great but it causes me to have a lot more messy html code where I have to initialize it. I would like to see if I can make it more generic where when an object is clicked, the javascript/jquery grabs the href and executes the rest of the function without the need for a unique ID on each object that's clicked.

code that works currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function linkPrepend(element){
    var divelement = document.getElementById(element);
    var href=$(divelement).attr('href');

    $.get(href,function (hdisplayed) {
     $("#content").empty()
     .prepend(hdisplayed);
        });
     }
 </script>
```

html:

```
<button id="test1" href="page1.html" onclick="linkPrepend('test1')">testButton1</button>

<button id="test2" href="page2.html" onclick="linkPrepend('test2')">testButton1</button>

    <!-- when clicking the button, it fills the div 'content' with the URL's html -->

        <div id="content"></div>
```

I'd like to end up having html that looks something like this:

```
<button href="page1.html" onclick="linkPrepend()">testButton1</button>

<button href="page2.html" onclick="linkPrepend()">testButton1</button>

<!-- when clicking the button, it fills the div 'content' with the URL's html -->

<div id="content"></div>
```

If there is even a simpler way of doing it please do tell. Maybe there could be a more generic way where the javascript/jquery is using an event handler and listening for a click request? Then I wouldn't even need a onclick html markup?

I would prefer if we could use pure jquery if possible.

Comment: `<!-- when clicking the button, it fills the div 'content' with the URL's html -->` seems like you are trying to create angularjs :)

Comment: Wow lots of great answers everybody! I now realize that I should have also asked about what is best for SEO? I do want my site to be SEO compliant so I don't hurt my pageranks. Is the data-href method the best way for SEO? Can I use data-href for other objects like LI's etc. without issues? Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to validate right you need to use HTML 5 Doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Won't really matter what Doctype you use, href  attribute in a button will pretty much always be wrong so try and use `data-*` instead and yes you can use that on any element

Comment: Thanks for all the great input guys! Much appreciated and gives me lots of great new knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking over the other responses this kinda combines them.

```
<button data-href="page2.html" class="show">testButton1</button>
<li data-href="page1.html" class="show"></li>
```

class gives you ability to put this specific javascript function on whatever you choose.

```
$(".show").click( function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("data-href");
    $.get(href,function (hdisplayed) {
        $("#content").html( hdisplayed );
    });
});
```

Comment: This one takes all the other answers and seems to work best in the end. Thanks for everyone's contributions!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` instead of an ID.

```
<button data-href="page2.html" onclick="linkPrepend(this)">testButton1</button>
```

and then use

```
function linkPrepend(element) {
    var href = $(this).data('href');

    $.get(href, function (hdisplayed) {
        $("#content").empty().prepend(hdisplayed);
    });
}
```

NOTE: You might have noticed that I changed `href` to `data-href`. This is because `href` is an invalid attribute for button so you should be using the HTML 5 `data-*` attributes.

But if you are using jQuery you should leave aside inline click handlers and use the jQuery handlers

```
<button data-href="page2.html">testButton1</button>
```

```
$(function () {
    $('#someparent button').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).data('href');
        $.get(href, function (hdisplayed) {
            $("#content").empty().prepend(hdisplayed);
        });
    });
});
```

`$('#someparent button')` here you can use CSS selectors to find the right buttons, or you can append an extra class to them.

Comment: The second example (jQuery) would not function as intended. `this.href` would return null value. http://jsfiddle.net/tf6t5bcg/1/

Comment: True, somehow I assumed `href` was a button property. Thank for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting up the click event in JavaScript (during onload or onready) instead of in your markup.  Put a common class on the buttons you want to apply this click event to.  For example:

```
<button class="prepend-btn" href="page2.html">testButton1</button>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Specify click event handler for every element containing the ".prepend-btn" class
        $(".prepend-btn").click(function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');  //this references the element that was clicked
            $.get(href, function (hdisplayed) {
                $("#content").empty().prepend(hdisplayed);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`href` is not a valid attribute for the [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html) element. You can instead use the [data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute to store custom properties. Your markup could then look like this

```
<button data-href="page1.html">Test Button 1</button>
<button data-href="page2.html">Test Button 1</button>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

From there you can use the [Has Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector to get all the buttons that have the `data-href` attribute. jQuery has a function called [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that will get content and load it into a target for you. So your script will look like

```
$('button[data-href]').on('click',function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).data('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished with some jQuery:

```
$("button.prepend").click( function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(href,function (hdisplayed) {
        $("#content").html( hdisplayed );
    });
});
```

And small HTML modifications (adding `prepend` class):

```
<button href="page1.html" class="prepend">testButton1</button>
<button href="page2.html" class="prepend">testButton2</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<button href="page1.html" class="showContent">testButton1</button>

<button href="page2.html"class="showContent">testButton1</button>

<!-- when clicking the button, it fills the div 'content' with the URL's html -->

<div id="content"></div>
```

JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('.showContent').click(function(){
         var $this = $(this),
             $href = $this.attr('href');

          $.get($href,function (hdisplayed) {
            $("#content").empty().prepend(hdisplayed);
        });
     }

    });

 </script>
```

Hope it helps.